# Convert a column of integers into a range of -50 to +50

Tags: excel, excel-formula, range

I have one column with around 800 (between 0 and 1000) random integers sorted in ascending order and I need to convert them into a range of -50 to +50, such that 0 corresponds to -50 and 1000 corresponds to +50.

Comment: *Help!* - What have **you** tried to accomplish this?

Comment: You mention other ranges like if value 500 what will then -50 or +50. If value is 700 or greater what will be result -50 or +50. Can you please explain more.

Comment: need some extra details

Comment: uh... maybe `=round(a1/10, 0)-50` ...

Answer (score 1):

=((A1/1000)*100)-50

Or, to round to whole numbers:

=ROUNDUP(((A1/1000)*100)-50,0)
=ROUNDDOWN(((A1/1000)*100)-50,0)